# cypress chai avoid printing the value

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cypress, chai

I am using expect to assert a string but it prints the value.
Below is the code

```
expect(USER).to.be.a('string').and.to.not.be.empty;
```

and this is how it prints in the cypress:
[image]

How should I avoid printing the value?

Answer (score 2):

Cypress modifies chai.expect but does not seem to add a way to turn off logging.

If you import from node_modules you can run the original and avoid the log.

```js
const chai = require('chai');

it('expects witout log', () => {
  chai.expect(USER).to.be.a('string').and.to.not.be.empty;  // no logging happening
})
```

Comment: I don't see this working, it looks like it just skips this line with your receommendation

Comment: No, it works. Change `string` to `number` and the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the value in `expect` param. For example:

```
expect(USER.length).to.be.greaterThan(1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).